# How to have a date based x axis and add vertical lines based on a list of dates with ggplot?

Tags: python, ggplot2

I have created this graph:

```
def myGraphNew (cc,ccBad,tY,tTitle):
    p1 = ggplot(cc, aes('DT', tY, color='Type')) + \
        geom_line(size=2.) + \
        xlab("Date") + \
        ggtitle(tTitle) + \
        scale_x_date(labels='%d-%b',breaks=date_breaks('week'))
    return p1
```

I supply this data to produce the base graph:

```
0 2016-09-22  Covered by Test       0.0
1 2016-09-25  Covered by Test       1.0
2 2016-09-26  Covered by Test      -3.0
3 2016-09-27  Covered by Test       1.0
4 2016-09-28  Covered by Test       5.0
5 2016-09-30  Covered by Test       0.0
6 2016-10-02  Covered by Test     113.0
7 2016-10-03  Covered by Test      67.0
8 2016-10-04  Covered by Test     105.0
0 2016-09-22            Total       0.0
1 2016-09-25            Total      47.0
2 2016-09-26            Total     -72.0
3 2016-09-27            Total     -13.0
4 2016-09-28            Total      16.0
5 2016-09-30            Total       0.0
6 2016-10-02            Total      58.0
7 2016-10-03            Total      77.0
8 2016-10-04            Total     334.0
```

I also have a list that contains a datetime I want to draw a vertical line for.  Currently this list only has one value but over time I expect that it will hold multiple values.  These dates are generated as part of the process that cleans the input data.

I have added the line

```
 geom_vline (xintercept=ccBad)
```

But I get the error
in axvline scalex = (xx < xmin) or (xx > xmax)

```
TypeError: unorderable types: float() > NoneType()
```

and the print of the graph shows this [after error graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOr71.png) with missing information rather than the graph that is produced without the geom_vline [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lSc6.png)